# Cant see http traffic using Proxyman when connecting to local machine

Tags: node.js, react-native, http

I am developing an app with a Node.js API with React Native client using Expo.
I am using a IOS emulator to test.

I have my API remotely on NodeChef and locally on my machine for dev.

Im using Proxyman 2.35.4 to watch for traffic. It is woking for the remote API
and I can see traffic under the "Apps" then "Expo" then it has the title of my remote endpoint "xx-xxxx-13442.nodechef.com".

But I cannot see traffic when I connect to the local machine API 192.168.1.4:4000. I have looked
all thru Apps and Domains folder.

Any ideas why?
Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

By default, all local traffic doesn't go through HTTP Proxy Server (Proxyman), so you might not see any localhost traffic.

To fix it, you might set it as an alias name, which you can add in the `/etc/hosts` file.

Here is the step:

1. Open `/etc/hosts` file
2. Add the following

```
127.0.0.1 myserver.local
::1 myserver.local
```

3. Save
4. Try to call myserver.local:4000

Then, Proxyman can capture this localhost traffic.

Ref: https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/couldnt-see-any-request-from-localhost-server